# Receive array and add array to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm implementing `React Hooks` on my code, but I'm having a problem.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_RATE":
      return {
        rates: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      throw new Error("Action type must be defined");
  }
}
```

Here I receive an array in `action.payload`, and I want to add this array to the `rates` state. However I receive the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).
>   If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How should I add this array to my state object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `action.payload` is an array? If yes then show how you are rendering that.

Comment: That error message is related to what your JSX is rendering. Odds are, you're doing something like this <p>{object}</p> by accident which React doesn't like.

Comment: if you're rendering the `rates` array then you should parse the new payload and generate React elements from it then add them to state

Comment: Can you post your JSX component? Where you're rendering this?

Comment: Yes, it was how I was rendering it. I was debugging the code and didn't realize I was using this state as an object. Mapping the object solved the issue. Thanks you guys